How to dynamically convert a class into an interface?
In TypeScript, if I have a class like this:
class A {
    private a:string;
    constructor(a:string) {
        this.a = a;
    }
    GetA() {
        return this.a;
    }

}

is there a way I can dynamically convert this to a type like this:
interface A {
    a:string;
}

I ask because, if I have a class instance and I pass it to a web worker, it seems to auto change the data type into a regular object with those properties, but no methods. So I would like to define a type to it, but I can't really use the class instance type, I would need a interface type to make it accurate.
Does anyone know how to do this?

If you change private a to public a or just a - this answer could help with the rest. playground

• The name A  is already taken by the class instance. You'd need to change the name of the second type. • You can't programmatically pull out private property types, so if a needs to be private then this is impossible.  • You can write a type like this that omits methods, although this isn't exactly the same as omitting prototype props (you can have an instance-specific method or a prototype-specific property, but these are rare). •  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?
